# "Alan's first birthday" vs. "Alans' first birthday"

Tags: punctuation, possessives

when writing out invitation cards would it be "Alans' first birthday" or "Alan's first birthday"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be better asked at our sister site for [ell.se]

Comment: Do you have two or more children named Alan both turning 1 that day?

Comment: The possessive of *Alan* is *Alan's*. Just like with every other noun (not ending in S) in existence.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that someone's name is `Alan`, then it should be `Alan's first birthday`.

The `'` Should only be added after the `s` when the word already ends with an `s`.

**Example**

The word `tree` Doesn't end with an `s` so we write:
`The forest is the tree's home.`

Now, consider the word `trees`. It already ends with `s`, so we write: `The forest is the trees' home.`

In the first example, it means: This is the home of a single tree. While in the second example it means: This is the home of multiple trees.

Note that when a non-plural word ends with an `s`, such as `canvas`, there isn't a strict rule and different people write it differently, either `canvas'` or `canvas's`. But the latter is prefered  because it actually tells you it's a single canvas, and not many. [See this site for more info](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/apostrophes/apostrophes-with-words-ending-in-s/)